# Why $scope is not working on the view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I got the next controller:

```
.controller('LogInController', function(logInFactory, $scope, $location, $state){
     $scope.logIn = function() {
            $scope.dataLoading = true;
            logInFactory.logIn($scope.email, $scope.password, function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $scope.userName = response.userName;
                    console.log('userName', $scope.userName);
                    logInFactory.setCredentials($scope.email, $scope.password);
                    $location.path('/users');
                } else {
                    $scope.dataLoading = false;
                }
            });
        };
    $scope.clearCredentials = function(){
        $state.go('login');
        logInFactory.clearCredentials();
    };    
});//End controller
```

I want to use it in this view:

```
<div class="header" ng-controller = 'LogInController'>
    <img src= "logo.jpg">
    {{userName}}
    <button ng-click = 'clearCredentials()'> Cerrar sesión</button>
</div>
```

But userName is not showing in the view but when I print it on the controller it is displayed correctly. That view is displayed after call the logIn() function.

This is the logIn function in my factory:

```
var logIn = function(email, password, callback){
            var URL;

            if(ENV.mocksEnable){
                URL = ENV.apiMock + ENV.logInMock;
                return (
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var response;
                        getUser()
                        .then(function (user) {
                            console.log('USER', user);
                            if (user !== null) {
                                response = { success: true, userName: user.userName};
                            } else {
                                response = { success: false, message: 'Username or password is incorrect' };
                            }
                            callback(response);
                        });
                    }, 1000)
                );
            }else{
                URL = ENV.apiURL + ENV.logIn;
                return (
                    $http.post(URL, {email : email, password : password})
                    .then(function onFulfilled(response){
                        var data = response.data;
                        userName = data.username;
                        userEmail = data.email;
                        userId  = data.id;
                        profiles = data.profiles;
                        callback(response);
                        return data;
                    })
                    .catch(function onRejected(errorResponse){
                        console.log('Error in logInFactory');
                        console.log('Status: ', errorResponse.status);
                        callback(errorResponse);
                        return errorResponse;
                    })
                );
            }
        };//End login
```

I trigger the logIn() function in this view

```
<form ng-submit = 'logIn()'>
  <h1>Log In</h1>       
  Correo electrónico:
  <input type="email" ng-model='email' required><br>
  Contraseña
  <input type="password" ng-model='password' required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

When I tigger logIn() I should go to that header and show the userName.

Comment: It's only being set in response.success. Maybe set it out of the login function so you know it's status if the request failed?

Comment: You may need to call `$scope.$apply()` or `$scope.$digest()` after setting it in the success callback.

Comment: Did you try to debug in a browser. Is username empty?

Comment: can you please show the code for clearCredentials() and your logInFactory

Comment: @Wcan  just did it

Comment: @CyberAleks in the console is not empty.

Comment: you have log in the console but the $scope is not shared between the factory and controller. the log come from the callback function you give to the factory but the controller don't get the $scope modification because it is made outside of it ( it is made in the factory and they don't share $scope )

Comment: The problem is that I set it in one view and tried to access it from another, but the controller resets its data when change the view.

Comment: if you want to share data between controller use service who are singleton ( it keep her value will the app is running even in controller change )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was expecting to get data from a controller to two different views. And when I go from LogIn view to my header view, the controller refresh its data.  So, I have to create in my factory:

```
var getUserName =  function() {
            return userName;
};
```

And in the controller

```
$scope.userName = logInFactory.getUserName();
```

Now my userName persists in the factory.

Comment: warning you cannot do this if your function is asynchrone ( with $http for example)

Answer (score 0):

why are you triggering `clearCredentials()` ? whereas according to this code you should triggering `login()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The result of your logIn() function may be out of Angular scope.

Try wrapping the result of the logIn function into a $timeout (which calls $apply, a way to force Angular to refresh a controller scope):

```
$timeout(function() {
    if (response.success) {
       $scope.userName = response.userName;
       console.log('userName', $scope.userName);
       logInFactory.setCredentials($scope.email, $scope.password);
       $location.path('/users');
    } else {
       $scope.dataLoading = false;
    }
});
```

Do not forget to inject the dependency $timeout in your controller.

Comment: What does console.log display ?

Comment: Display: userName Kimy

Answer (score 0):

You have $scope.userName inside the success of the logIn method. It won't be available until that has happened.

If you put $scope.userName outside of the method and set it to something, it would appear.

```
.controller('LogInController', function(logInFactory, $scope, $location, $state) {
  $scope.userName = 'test name';
  $scope.logIn = function() { ...
```

Something like that.

Comment: Yes, but always prints 'test name'.But I want to initialize it depending on the response.

Comment: Assuming your code is working as it should, i.e. the login part, then the part where you have .then(function(success) { }) should be able to set the $scope.userName to what the name is when they log in.

Answer (score 0):

we don't have your factory code but  this line is very strange to me :

```
logInFactory.logIn($scope.email, $scope.password, function (response) { ..; } )
```

so your passing the fonction to the factory and it is not the factory who returning data to the controller.

it should be something like this :

```
logInFactory.logIn($scope.email, $scope.password).then(function (response) { ..; } );
```

EDIT : 
You have to remove the callback function from your factory and make the factory  return data and handle data like this `logInFactory.logIn($scope.email, $scope.password).then(function (response) { ..; } );`.

You have log in the console but the $scope is not shared between the factory and controller so the callback in your factory edit the `$scope.userName` but the controller cannot get this change.

Comment: I just posted the logIn() function in the factory